# Service to give access to download after Tweet / FB Like etc

Tags: facebook, twitter

I remember stumbling across a free service that you could integrate with your website that would give visitors access to a download (PDF/ebook/white paper etc) if you Tweeted/ Facebook Liked etc. but for the life of me I can't find it now.

Does anyone have any recommendations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Was it http://www.paywithatweet.com/ ?
For Wordpress there's a plugin: 
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tweet2download/

I haven't used either, so I can't recommend them.

Comment: Thakns - actually I've found it now (same as pay with a tweet but also does DB) http://www.cloudflood.com/

Answer (score 1):

http://www.cloudflood.com/ - Does Twitter and Facebook

*(No connection and not yet used it)*

Answer (score 1):

http://www.estago.com/ Twitter and Facebook